# How do I disable a log channel on local and testing environment

Tags: laravel, logging, development-environment, production-environment

In my application I have these log channels:

```
'general'       => [
 'driver' => 'single',
 'path'   => storage_path('logs/general.log'),
 'level'  => 'debug',
],
'jobs'    => [
  'driver'   => 'stack',
  'channels' => [
    'general',
    'slack'
 ],
],
'slack'         => [
    'driver'   => 'slack',
    'url'      => /*Censored Hook URL*/,
    'username' => 'MyApp',
    'emoji'    => ':gear:',
    'level'    => 'debug',
],
```

When I log in `job` channel I want not to log into `slack` log when on local or testing environment in order to avoid having duplicate and extremely unwanted logs on the shared log channel on the slack.

So how I can specify the environments that the `slack` channel will be able to write logs. A dirty approach is to specify manually which logs will write in to via this snippet of code:

```
if(!App::environment(['local','testing')){
   Log::channel('jobs')->info('Blah blah blah');
} else {
   Log::channel('general')->info('Blah blah blah');
}
```

But using the code above, I am afraid that will turn my codebase into a diffucult-to-read-one. So do you know an elegant solution in order to process my logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply split `jobs` into 2 entrys, example `jobs` and `jobs_without_slack`, let `jobs` be as is and `jobs_without_slack` will be configured without `slack` in it's `channels`. Then use different `.env.xy` files for testing (`.env.testing`), local, develop (`.env.develop`) and so on and set the `LOG_CHANNEL` to the correct logging, so you do not need to change a line of code in your logic ;)